# Awkward comparison of functions in PHP

Tags: php, comparison

So I've got this snippet:

```
function compare1($s1, $s2)
{
    return $s1===$s2;
}

function compare2($s1, $s2)
{
    return !strcmp($s1, $s2);
}

function challenge($s1, $s2) //Objective: return TRUE
{
    return compare1($s1, $s2) ^ compare2($s1, $s2);
}
```

What's requested from me is to supply/append/assign values to the $s1 and $s2 variables so as for the last function to return TRUE.

I've tried nearly everything I could think of, like `$s1='1' and $s2=1` which does return TRUE:

> var_dump(compare1('1', 1) ^ compare2('1', 1)); //output: int 1

Creator of the challenge told me that I shouldn't or rather can't assign integer values to the variables but issue is that no boolean variations worked. Here is the website I'm talking about so as you can see if you could possibly come up with a solution: http://securitytraps.no-ip.org/challs/strcmp/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you could change the return to be: `return (bool)(compare1($s1, $s2) ^ compare2($s1, $s2));`

Comment: `false` and `null` would easily work, also `"array"` and `array()` (although the last would issue a warning). There are several options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$s1= null;
$s2 = "";
```

This does not work on the tool provided but works from the command line.

also

```
$s1 = "";
$s2 = false;
```

Comment: Exactly the issue I've ran into - able to output TRUE on my localhost but the site does not validate it properly. Consulted with the creator and it's confirmed it works fine.

Comment: I think the site is treating all inputs as strings so "" is becoming `'""'` and null is becoming `"null"`

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the first give away is that the site is a security trap site so they are looking to show you vulnerabilities in PHP.  So while the other answers are valid they don't work when being passed over the internet.

To solve the challenge you actually have to modify the HTML on the page and turn one of the keys into an array like: `<input name="s2[]" value="s2" />` and then submit the form. When that happens the strcmp will compare $_POST['s1'] (string) with $_POST['s2'] (array) causing PHP to evaluate the strcmp as true!

Comment: +1 was able to reproduce as you described ... got 'Password: 4Rr41nGtrick' after a warning.

Comment: You're right. Tricky part, never thought of this before. Thanks for the help :)